# How to push to multiple remotes from multiple branches individually at once?

Tags: git, git-remote

So, the situation is like this:
Say I have 3 branches in my local git repo: **master**, **dev**, **staging**.

Now, I have different servers for each branch that I want to push to.
For example I have set *prodS* (prodServer) as remote to master and have it mapped to master(git push -set--upstream prodS master). So that `git push` pushes master to prodS when I have checkedout master.

Similarly,
*devS* for *dev* branch,
*stagingS* for *staging* branch

When my *dev* and *staging* branches are ready for push, (Regardless of which branch I have currently checkedout,) I want to be able to run a single command that pushes *dev* to *devS* and *staging* to *stagingS*; instead of having to switch to each branch and then run `git push` or run `git push devS dev` and so forth for each branch since I already mapped *dev* to *devS/dev*.

> I'm aware that multiple URLs can be added to a remote. But that is not
> what I'm looking for. Say there are already multiple remotes added to
> each of the branches. But I added them to a particular branch because
> I want only that particular branch on those remote/s. That's already
> ok and working.

Is there such an option in git itself? Or the only option here maybe some other workaround like a script?

**EDIT: To simpify, and make it easier to understand the question,**
If `git pull --all` pulls from all remote branches tracked by all local  branches; shouldn't `git push --all` work in similar way?

Comment: You can specify the remote and the branch on git push without having to have that branch checked out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pull/push from multiple remote locations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/how-can-i-pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations)

Comment: @Steve No I don't want that as mentioned in my question, and No. I know it's easy to confuse it with the question you mentioned. But it's a completely different scenario. I know how to add and use multiple remotes to a particular branch. My question is: after doing above on different branches, how to push each branch to it's respective remote/s at once.

Comment: [Pedro Sousa's alias suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72474379/1256452), or a shell alias that invokes multiple `git push` commands, is going to be the way to go. Remember that the syntax for `git push` is `git push <repository> <refspec>...` so you can list the refspec you want pushed and not use `HEAD` and you won't be referring to your current branch.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is an option to specify multiple branches for multiples remotes in a single push, but I think there are a couple alternatives that might be useful.

**1. Multiple push urls for a single remote:**

If you are fine with having your `dev` branch on `stagingS` and your `staging` branch on `devS` then you can define a new remote `<name>` and set the urls for both `devS` and `stagingS` as push urls for this new remote:

```
$ git remote set-url --add --push <name> <url-for-devS>
$ git remote set-url --add --push <name> <url-for-stagingS>
```

Now you can push both dev and staging to both remotes with `git push <name> dev staging`

**2. Aliases**

You probably know this already, but you can set a new command on your `.git/config` file (or even `~/.gitconfig` if this behaviour is something you need over multiple projects) under the `alias` section and you will be able to use it as a git command, even using normal flags for the `push` command like `-v` and `-f`.

```
[alias]
    my-command = !git push devS dev $* && git push stagingS staging $*
```

Now you can run `git my-command -f`, for example.

Comment: For solution 1: I have mapped remote/s to particular branches only because i don't want other branches on those remote/s.

Comment: For solution 2: It seems like a good idea and I will explore it.
But I would still prefer if there was some other native git way of doing it.
Maybe something as simple as `git push *`  ?

Comment: Maybe something as simple as `git push *`  ?
This should work since 1st argument after push is supposed to be a remote. So I want to push to all remotes. But if I'm not specifying a branch as 2nd argument, it should push the branch the remote is mapped to. 
I know this wouldn't work. But just an idea or hint about the kind of solution I need.